# Python Runtime Error, Minimum Time Requred problem

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime-error

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

class Fraction:

    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def return_whole(self):
        return self.numerator // self.denominator


def function1(machines, goal, try_day):
    day = try_day

    tmp_sum = 0

    for element in machines:
        fraction = Fraction(1 * day, element)
        whole = fraction.return_whole()
        tmp_sum += whole

    if tmp_sum >= goal:
        return day

    return False


def recursion_my(machines, goal, lst):
    length = len(lst)

    if length >= 3:
        if not function1(machines, goal, lst[length // 2 - 1]) and function1(machines, goal,lst[length // 2 + 1]):
            if function1(machines, goal, lst[length // 2]):
                return lst[length // 2]

            return lst[length // 2 + 1]

        if function1(machines, goal, lst[length // 2 - 1]):
            return recursion_my(machines, goal, lst[: length // 2])

        else:
            return recursion_my(machines, goal, lst[length // 2:])
    else:
        for i in range(length):
            if function1(machines, goal, lst[i]):
                return lst[i]


def min_time(machines, goal):

    day = min(machines) * goal
    days = []

    for i in range(0, day + 1):
        days.append(i)

    return recursion_my(machines, goal, days)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    nGoal = input().split()

    n = int(nGoal[0])

    goal = int(nGoal[1])

    machines = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    ans = min_time(machines, goal)

    fptr.write(str(ans) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

so i got a straight question: i am solving https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/tsu-advanced-course-in-algorithms-homework-6/challenges/minimum-time-required/copy-from/1311175267 this problem and on some test cases(5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12) i got a *Runtime* error. I know there is something obvious mistake but please help me to understand it.I suppose code might be written easier and cleaner way but firstly i would like to know what did i wrong then i would be happy to see your ideas too.

Comment: _i got a Runtime error_ Show us the complete error message.

Comment: that's a problem. Test cases are on the site and i have not access on whole Error Message... It only says that i got a Runtime Error :(

Comment: @John Gordon, Hackerrank does not always show what the error is. It just returns a status message for each test case (correct, wrong, time limit exceeded, run time error).

Comment: @Zura - the link is not open to the public (and also indicates that it is your homework). Can you share some information about the question?

Comment: Is it possible to get a division by zero error?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-time-required/problem @doodhwala yep sry i am newbie.

Comment: @doodhwala i don't think so, denominator is always more than 0, isn't it?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that it's either an out of memory error or exceeded maximum recursion depth. One pointer that I can give you, is to come up with a better solution. I'd love to tell the order of magnitude as a hint, but that might be a giveaway.

Comment: you mean completely other solution ? Yeh i thought about exceeding maximum recursion depth